# The operator norm and the spectral radius

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory

Let $\mathcal{B}(F)$ the algebra of all bounded linear operators on an infinite-dimensional complex Hilbert space $F$.

It is well know that if $A$ is **normal operator**, then $r(A)=\|A\|$.

> I want to find an example of operator $A$ which is **not normal** but 
>   $$r(A)=\|A\|,$$
>   where $r(A)$ and $\|A\|$ denotes respectively the spectral radius of $A$ and the norm of $A$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $F= \ell_2$ and $A \in \mathcal{B}(F)$ be given by

$A(x_1,x_2,x_3,....)=(0,x_1,x_2,x_3,...)$.

Then we have $||A||=1$ and $ \sigma(A)=\{z \in \mathbb K:|z| \le 1\}$, hence $r(A)=1$.

Furthermore: $A^*A=I \ne AA^*$.

Comment: Very nice - this construction provides a counterexample even in $\mathbb{C}^3$ if one wants a finite-dimensional version.

Comment: Is the numerical radius of $A$ is also equals to 1?

Comment: Yes. If we denote the numerical radius of $A$ by $n(A)$, then it is well known that $r(A) \le n(A) \le ||A||$.